# Добавление папок и файлов в конечный zip архив шаблона проекта VS 2015 во время сборки

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions, шаблоны-проектов

После создания проекта Visual Studio (**Visual C#\Extensibility\C# Project Template**), удаления тега **`<Project></Project>`** вместе с его содержимым в файле MyTemplate.vstemplate мы получаем вот такой проект:

[image: Mytemplate]

После сборки этого проекта в папке `bin\` образуется архив с двумя файлами:

[image: MyTemplate.zip]

Как настроить проект таким образом, что-бы при сборке в этот архив ложилась ещё произвольная папка с произвольными файлами из проекта?

[image: ExampleFolder]

При этом нельзя что-бы шаблон генерировал все эти файлы при запуске его ярлыка из VisualStudio(т.е. нельзя добавлять файлы в файл с расширением **.vstemplate** как я понимаю)

*(А делать этого нельзя т.к. этот шаблон используется для вызова WizardTemplate который уже сам генерирует шаблон по пути который передан от самого Template. А собственно файлы которые находятся в шаблоне по условию нужно использовать в этом Wizard'e. Такие дела)*

Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смог решить данную проблему с помощью Post Build Action.
Файлы прикрепил к проекту с действием при компилляции "None", а в PostBuildAction написал скрипт доупаковку архива zip с помощью утилиты 7z.